# Google app engine bulkloader opens empty file at upload

Tags: google-app-engine, development-environment, bulkloader

I'm running the following two commands:

```
appcfg.py download_data --kind=Journal --url=http://appname.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=Journals.sql3
appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api --kind=Journal --filename=Journals.sql3
```

The first one successfully downloads the data in the following files:
bulkloader-results-20130718.112127.sql3
Journals.sql3
No errors whatsoever. When I open the file in notepad, it looks like the data is in there.

The second one opens a random new empty file each time I run it (e.g. bulkloader-progress-20130718.115805.sql3). Then it gives the following error log:

```
INFO     2013-07-18 11:54:48,930 module.py:595] default: "POST /_ah/remote_api HTTP/1.1" 200 96
INFO     2013-07-18 11:58:17,563 module.py:595] default: "GET /_ah/remote_api?rtok=36123921049 HTTP/1.1" 200 64
INFO     2013-07-18 11:58:20,609 module.py:595] default: "GET /_ah/remote_api HTTP/1.1" 200 37
ERROR    2013-07-18 09:58:20,618 handler.py:384] Exception while handling service_name: "datastore_v4"
method: "AllocateIds"
request: ""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\handler.py", line 380, in post
    response_data = self.ExecuteRequest(request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\handler.py", line 411, in ExecuteRequest
    response_data)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 328, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 234, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    raise pickle.loads(response_pb.exception())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'THREADSAFE'
INFO     2013-07-18 11:58:20,622 module.py:595] default: "POST /_ah/remote_api HTTP/1.1" 200 96
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Still no solution. What is funny is that uploading on the app engine server does work.

Comment: The random named filesare progress files, you can name progress files explicitly which allows you to restart a halted upload or download.  They are not your problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for clearing that out. Any idea what could cause the error?

Comment: Unfortunately not, what SDK version and python version are you using ?

Comment: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.5/ and https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python on Windows 8 (just downloaded yesterday, as I have a new laptop)

Comment: Also removing '--kind=Journal' does not work.

Comment: The problem as the error states is with `AllocateIds` this service is used when uploading to ensure the same id's are allocated to the uploaded entities.  Is the local dev datastore empty ?  Also do you have auto_id_policy set in your app.yaml ?

Comment: It's empty in terms of Journals, but there's a few other objects in there already. There's no auto_id_policy set. I didn't set this policy in my previous development environment.

Comment: Tried emptying the datastore & setting the auto_id_policy. Nothing works.. Any ideas?

Comment: Also tried turning threadsafe off, no effect.

Comment: I have the same problem here. I recently installed the latest SDK version 1.8.2. How about you?

Comment: Yes, I have the newest one also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there's a [ticket](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9666&q=THREADSAFE&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log#makechanges) for this issue, and it's related to the latest version of the Python dev server (1.8.2).

As suggested on the ticket, I downgraded my dev server to the previous SDK version (1.8.1) and bulk upload worked as expected again.

Comment: new version 1.8.3 has the same problem.