# No api proxy found for service "datastore_v4" in new GAE 1.8.4

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I try to upload the data into datastore use remote_api at my dev server, but I got the following error, the SDK version is 1.8.4. Is there anyone has the same error? It looks like the new datastore version 4 cause this?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 184, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 180, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4
403, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4
394, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2
469, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4
103, in __call__
    return method()
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3
915, in PerformUpload
    run_fn(args)
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3
806, in RunBulkloader
    sys.exit(bulkloader.Run(arg_dict))
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkloader.py", li
ne 4419, in Run
    return _PerformBulkload(arg_dict)
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkloader.py", li
ne 4284, in _PerformBulkload
    loader.finalize()
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\bulkload\bulkloader_
config.py", line 382, in finalize
    self.reserve_keys(self.keys_to_reserve)
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkloader.py", li
ne 1228, in ReserveKeys
    datastore._GetConnection()._reserve_keys(ConvertKeys(keys))
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastore\datastore_rpc.
py", line 1880, in _reserve_keys
    self._async_reserve_keys(None, keys).get_result()
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastore\datastore_rpc.
py", line 838, in get_result
    results = self.__rpcs[0].get_result()
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py
", line 612, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastore\datastore_rpc.
py", line 1921, in __reserve_keys_hook
    self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastore\datastore_rpc.
py", line 1234, in check_rpc_success
    rpc.check_success()
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py
", line 578, in check_success
    self.__rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", li
ne 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_ap
i_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "D:\python-lib\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_ap
i_stub.py", line 234, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    raise pickle.loads(response_pb.exception())
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "datastore_v4"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this won't work until 1.8.6 as there is another bug (see [Google app engine bulkloader opens empty file at upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720516/google-app-engine-bulkloader-opens-empty-file-at-upload)). For the time being you have to go back to 1.8.1 to find a working version.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for this is to use `appcfg.py` from the 1.8.3 SDK (and then update to 1.8.5 as soon as it's out).